# Type of audio codec being played in VLC

Tags: vlc-media-player, aac

Is there a way in VLC player to ascertain the audio codec being used while playing a live stream via URL ?

I am able to see "Codec: MPEG AAC Audio" in Codec Info but I want to see what type of AAC is being used i.e. is it AAC-LC, AAC-LD, AAC-ELD.

If it is not possible via VLC, to view such information, is their some other player that can help me out here ?

Comment: I am streaming an MPEG2-TS stream via RTSP, and ffmpeg/ffplay does not seem to play the same when I plug in the URL with them.

Answer (score 2):

VLC does not make available a more detailed information than what you are seeing.
To get more detailed information, you need to use a utility that
better analyzes the network stream.

I recommend using [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo),
available on every major operating system.
You may enter the URL after invoking `mediainfo`, or by using the following
command line (which didn't work for me on Windows):

```
mediainfo URL
```

Taking as example this
[test media URL](https://www.radiantmediaplayer.com/media/bbb-360p.mp4),
VLC gives this information:

[image]

While mediainfo gives much more:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this. :D

Comment: So I tried the command, but it seems mediainfo does not take in rtsp URLs. Bad Luck !

Comment: Do you have an example URL?

Comment: Yes. "rtsp://<ip_address>:<port_number>/<stream_name>". For example: "rtsp://192.168.201.197:8901/live".

Comment: I am using Live555 to generate this rtsp url.

Comment: RTSP for mediainfo is a [feature request](https://sourceforge.net/p/mediainfo/feature-requests/207/) dating from 2009. If you are into C programming, the you could use [Gstreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/media-information-gathering.html). Apart from that, I can only think of capturing the video and post-analyzing it.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help. (y)